# multi object PDO Json Response

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to send a set of queries with PDO and then return a multi-object JSON response and everything is working fine except for json_encode is returning my objects with index number  and I can't find a way to return as named objects so I can use it later in javascrip as

```
data.address.StreetName
```

like:

```
    {
        "adddress": {
            "StreetName": "bla bla bla",
            "number": "123"
        }

        "device": {
            "deviceName": "bla bla bla",
            "deviceID": "123"
        }

    }
```

this is my php code

```
     $stmt = $db_con->prepare($q);
     $stmt->execute()
     $address = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     $stmt = $db_con->prepare($q);
     $stmt->execute()
     $device = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $json = json_encode(array($address,$device));
```

I'm currently getting

```
    [["StreetName": "bla bla bla",
            "number": "123"],
    ["deviceName": "bla bla bla",
            "deviceID": "123"]
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the keys:

```
$json = json_encode(array('address' => $address, 'device' => $device));
```

Or:

```
$json = json_encode(compact('address', 'device'));
```